# deps.json does not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I Try execute Add-migration but show Error(build successful)
The specified deps.json [D:\Projects\Register\Register\Register.deps.json] does not exist

deps.json location in bin Foolder but Search it in root of Project

how To Resolve it?

Comment: Did you find a fix?  I'm having the same problem when trying to scaffold. I been trying everything and have not found a solution yet. Only started happening recently. VS2019  16.10.1

Comment: No i didn't found solution

Comment: In my case it looked like the project type was the cause. I had selected Blazor wasm project by mistake. I didn’t have the same issue with server side Blazor project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the server project not client project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).